# Inserting rows where column can have many values

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored proc that inserts rows into a table.  The issue is that many of the columns can have a list of different values and all of the rows in the db need to reflect these values.  For example:

I have a table: Table1(state, number)

state will need to be 1-50 as its value and number is 1-3.  There needs to be a row for each state with each number.

(1,1)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,1)...etc

There has got to be a nice way to do this but my research has not been fruitful.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You want to create a row for each permutation? Will non permuted data be in some other table where it is not needlessley repeated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to generate the values is using a `cross join`.  Here is an example:

```
insert into table(state, number)
      select s.state, n.number
      from (select 'AK' as state union all select 'AL'  union all . . .
           ) s cross join
           (select 1 as number union all select 2 union all select 3
           ) n
```

You may already have a lists of states and/or numbers, in which case you can use this.  For example:

```
insert into table(state, number)
      select s.state, n.number
      from (select state from states
           ) s cross join
           (select 1 as number union all select 2 union all select 3
           ) n
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need is a cross join between two tables, one containing 50 rows, the other 3 rows.

In Oracle:

```
select *
from
(
  select rownum as state
  from dual
  connect by rownum <= 50
) t1
, 
(
  select rownum as num
  from dual
  connect by rownum <= 3
) t2
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10400/0)